# Rails controller if else statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, message

I'm working on a messaging system in my rails web app at the moment which should give users the capability to see their sent and received messages. Sent and received messages are defined in my model as 'to_messages' and 'from_messages'. As it stands, I'm able to display the appropriate messages for both the inbox and outbox. When a user goes into the inbox and clicks on a received message, the show action displays the content. However, this is not working for the sent messages in the outbox. When a user clicks on a sent messages in the outbox, I get an error, which I suspect I'm getting because in my messages controller, I'm only calling to_messages(received messages). I know that I need an if/else statement in my controller, but I'm not sure how to go about writing it out. Apologies for the newbie question, but does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

messages_controller.rb

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @messages = current_user.to_messages
  end

  def outbox
    type = (params[:type] && params[:type] == "sent" ) ? "from_messages" : "to_messages"
    @messages = current_user.from_messages
  end

  def show
    @message = current_user.to_messages.find params[:id]
  end

  def new
    @message = Message.new
    @recipient = User.find(params[:user_id])
  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new message_params
    @message.sender_id = current_user.id
    if @message.save
      flash[:success] = "Your message has been sent!"
      redirect_to users_path
    else
      flash[:failure] = "Please try again."
      redirect_to users_path
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @message = Message.find(params[:id])
    @message.destroy
    redirect_to messages_path
  end

  private

  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:content, :sender_id, :recipient_id)
  end

end
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I get the following error, Couldn't find Message with 'id'=3 [WHERE "messages"."recipient_id" = ?], its looking to my messages#show action
    @message = current_user.to_messages.find params[:id]

Comment: TRy using current_user.to_messages.where(:id => params[:id])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured it out. AllI had to do was change the code in my Messages#show action to the following:

```
def show
  @message = Message.find params[:id]
end
```

Thanks anyway for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your method for outbox messages seems to try to handle both 'from_messages' and 'to_messages' but then does nothing with the information:

```
def outbox
  type = (params[:type] && params[:type] == "sent" ) ? "from_messages" : "to_messages"
  @messages = current_user.from_messages
end
```

Once you have type (from_messages or to_messages), here is what you could do:

```
def outbox
  type = (params[:type] && params[:type] == "sent" ) ? "from_messages" : "to_messages"
  @messages = current_user.send(type.to_sym)
end
```

Your 'show' action doesnt seem to be handling from_messages as well. It may be necessary to send the type there too:

```
def show
   type = (params[:type] && params[:type] == "sent" ) ? "from_messages" : "to_messages"       
   @message = current_user.send(type.to_sym).find params[:id]
end
```

And here is a DRY solution:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :find_type, only: [:outbox, :show]

  def index
    @messages = current_user.to_messages
  end

  def outbox
    @messages = current_user.send(@type.to_sym)
  end

  def show
    @message = current_user.send(@type.to_sym).find params[:id]
  end

  ...
  Rest of controller
  ...

private

  def find_type
    @type = (params[:type] && params[:type] == "sent" ) ? "from_messages" : "to_messages"
  end

end
```